# How can I train myself in pawn endgames?

Tags: software, endgame, training, pawn-endgame

I'm looking for a chess program which offers to play pawn endgames to improve myself.
For example, can I force Fritz 13 to play pawns endgames? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any chess-playing computer program that allows you to set up positions can be used. And yes, Fritz is especially suited for this.

You have several options:

1. [Set up the position yourself](http://www.chesscentral.com/Fritz_Chess_Opening_a/136.htm) (using board/position set up). Choose any position that you want to get better at. Save that position and play against the computer.

   1a. I used to do this for simple pawn endings. I'd play both colors until I figured out some aspects of the pawn ending.

   1b. I'd often set up one side with an advantage (say an extra pawn) and see if I could win easily. (Since the computer plays well, this is not easy to do in practice.)
2. You can start collecting some endgame positions, from a book or from around the web, create a small endgame learning database for yourself, and practice.
3. [In this video](http://chessimprover.com/using-fritz-13-for-endgame-training/) (be sure to watch) Nigel Davies recommends Silman's *Complete Endgame Course* (I find most things by Silman to be very good.)
4. Finally, if you don't mind spending a little, "Fritz Endgame Trainers" (DVD or software add-ons) that ChessBase sells are quite good. (Just buy one at a time, and be sure to read the reviews to see if it is at the right level for your needs.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know some free chess database online to download for pawns endgames training? (Fritz 13 compatible will be perfect)